# Dynamically change what is being awked

Tags: unix, dynamic, awk, grep

I have this input below:

```
 IDNO     H1  H2  H3    HT   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5    M1  M2  EXAM

 OUT OF  100 100 150   350   30 30 30 30 30   100 150   400

 1434    22  95 135   252   15 20 12 18 14    45 121   245

 1546     99 102 140   341   15 17 14 15 23    91 150   325

 2352     93  93 145   331   14 17 23 14 10    81 101   260

(et cetera)

          H1  H2  H3    HT   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5    M1  M2  EXAM
 OUT OF  100 100 150   350   30 30 30 30 30   100 150   400
```

I need to use write a unix script to use the awk function to dynamically find any column that is entered in and have it displayed to the screen.  I have successfully awked specific columns, but I cant seem to figure out how to make it change based on different columns.  My instructor will simply pick a column for test data and my program needs to find that column.

what I was trying was something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

awk {'print $(I dont know what goes here)'} testdata.txt
```

EDIT: Sorry i should have been more specific, he is entering in the header name as the input. for example `"H3"`. Then it needs to awk that.

Comment: @joepd yes, I tried to retag as [homework] but saw that that tag is being obsoleted.

Comment: Its a very very small part of a very very large homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just looking for:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk 'NR==1{ for( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) if( $i == header ) col=i }
  { print $col }' header=${1?No header entered} testdata.txt
```

This makes no attempt to deal with a column header that does not appear
in the input.  (Left as an exercise for the reader.)

Answer (score 0):

Your line format has a lot of variation (in the number of fields). That said, what about something like this:

```
echo "Which column name?"
read column
case $column in
  (H1) N=2;;
  (H2) N=3;;
  (H3) N=4;;
  ...
  (*) echo "Please try again"; exit 1;;
esac
awk -v N=$N '{print $N}' testdata.txt
```

Comment: Sorry i should have been more specific, he is entering in the header name as the input.  for example "H3".  Then it needs to awk that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you question is quite diffuse and in principle you want someone else write your awk script... You should check man pages for awk, they are quite descriptive.

my 2 cent wort, as an example would be (for the row) :
myscript.sh:

```
#/bin/sh
cat $1 | awk -v a=$2 -v b=$3 '{if ($(a)==b){print $0}}';
```

if you just want a column, well,

```
#/bin/sh
cat $1 | awk -v a=$2 '{print $(a)}';
```

Your input would be :

> myscript.sh file_of_data col_num

Again, reiterating: Please study man pages of awk. Also please when asking question present what you have tried (code) and errors (logs). This will make people more ready to help you.

Comment: Useless use of cat: `awk ... < $1`. In some (oldish) shells, the extra semicolon is a syntax error.

Comment: `{if ($(a)==b){print $0}}` is more idiomatically written `$a == b`